# Powershell using Select-String gives no results

Tags: powershell, select-string

I have the following command

```
Get-WindowsDriver -Online -All |  where {$_.ClassName -like "Display"}
```

This gives me the result like this

```
Driver           : vrd.inf
OriginalFileName : C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\vrd.inf_amd64_3a0ba97737bffd01\vrd.inf
Inbox            : True
ClassName        : Display
BootCritical     : False
ProviderName     : Microsoft
Date             : 6/21/2006 12:00:00 AM
Version          : 10.0.18362.329

Driver           : wvmbusvideo.inf
OriginalFileName : C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\wvmbusvideo.inf_amd64_483a786e00a2cb7a\wvmbusvideo.inf
Inbox            : True
ClassName        : Display
BootCritical     : False
ProviderName     : Microsoft
Date             : 6/21/2006 12:00:00 AM
Version          : 10.0.18362.1
```

Now I want to extract only the OriginalFileName line of both results so my output would look like this

```
OriginalFileName : C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\vrd.inf_amd64_3a0ba97737bffd01\vrd.inf
OriginalFileName : C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\wvmbusvideo.inf_amd64_483a786e00a2cb7a\wvmbusvideo.inf
```

Now to obtain the above result i can do this

```
Get-WindowsDriver -Online -All |  where {$_.ClassName -like "Display"} | findstr OriginalFileName
```

but the problem with the above command is that findstr has a character limit from what I have read, because of that some of the paths are cut. So in order to resolve that I am trying to use Select-String. This is what I am doing

```
Get-WindowsDriver -Online -All |  where {$_.ClassName -like "Display"} | Select-String -Pattern "OriginalFileName"
```

but I am not getting any results. Any suggestions on what I might be doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [Get-WindowsDriver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/dism/get-windowsdriver?view=win10-ps) returns **objects** (Microsoft.Dism.Commands.BasicDriverObject and/or Microsoft.Dism.Commands.AdvancedDriverObject), you should not use Select-String to find a single property of these objects.

Simply return them like

```
(Get-WindowsDriver -Online -All |  Where-Object {$_.ClassName -like "Display*"}).OriginalFileName
```

If you want the output to look like `PropertyName: PropertyValue`, you could use

```
Get-WindowsDriver -Online -All |  Where-Object {$_.ClassName -like "Display*"} | 
                                  Select-Object OriginalFileName | Format-List
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes findstr is a good search technique. `/i` makes it case insensitive.

Sometimes select-string or where { $_ -match 'whatever' } works.  It depends on how the object converts to a string.

```
[pscustomobject]@{name='joe'},[pscustomobject]@{name='bill'} | select-string b

@{name=bill}


[pscustomobject]@{name='joe'},[pscustomobject]@{name='bill'} | where { $_ -match 'b' }

name
----
bill
```

Unfortunately get-windowsdriver just converts to "Microsoft.Dism.Commands.BasicDriverObject":

```
$a = Get-WindowsDriver -Online -All | where ClassName -eq Display
$a[0].ToString()

Microsoft.Dism.Commands.BasicDriverObject


$a | select-string dism

Microsoft.Dism.Commands.BasicDriverObject
Microsoft.Dism.Commands.BasicDriverObject
Microsoft.Dism.Commands.BasicDriverObject
```